# How to tell if a Map has a default value?

Tags: scala, dictionary, default-value

Is there a way to check if a `Map` has a defined default value? What I would like is some equivalent of `myMap.getOrElse(x, y)` where if the key `x` is not in the map,

- if `myMap` has a default value, return that value
- else return `y`

A contrived example of the issue:

```
scala> def f(m: Map[String, String]) = m.getOrElse("hello", "world")
f: (m: Map[String,String])String

scala> val myMap = Map("a" -> "A").withDefaultValue("Z")
myMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(a -> A)

scala> f(myMap)
res0: String = world
```

In this case, I want `res0` to be `"Z"` instead of `"world"`, because `myMap` was defined with that as a default value. But `getOrElse` doesn't work that way.

---

I could use `m.apply` instead of `m.getOrElse`, but the map is not guaranteed to have a default value, so it could throw an exception (I could catch the exception, but this is nonideal).

```
scala> def f(m: Map[String, String]) = try {
     |   m("hello")
     | } catch {
     |   case e: java.util.NoSuchElementException => "world"
     | }
f: (m: Map[String,String])String

scala> val myMap = Map("a" -> "A").withDefaultValue("Z")
myMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(a -> A)

scala> f(myMap)
res0: String = Z

scala> val mapWithNoDefault = Map("a" -> "A")
mapWithNoDefault: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(a -> A)

scala> f(mapWithNoDefault)
res1: String = world
```

The above yields the expected value but seems messy. I can't pattern match and call `apply` or `getOrElse` based on whether or not the map had a default value, because the type is the same (`scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]`) regardless of default-ness.

Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve catching exceptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check whether the map is an instance of `Map.WithDefault`:

```
implicit class EnrichedMap[K, V](m: Map[K, V]) {
  def getOrDefaultOrElse(k: K, v: => V) =
    if (m.isInstanceOf[Map.WithDefault[K, V]]) m(k) else m.getOrElse(k, v)
}
```

And then:

```
scala> val myMap = Map("a" -> "A").withDefaultValue("Z")
myMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(a -> A)

scala> myMap.getOrDefaultOrElse("hello", "world")
res11: String = Z

scala> val myDefaultlessMap = Map("a" -> "A")
myDefaultlessMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(a -> A)

scala> myDefaultlessMap.getOrDefaultOrElse("hello", "world")
res12: String = world
```

Whether this kind of reflection is any better than using exceptions for non-exceptional control flow is an open question.

Comment: Oh, `Map.WithDefault` is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this is still kind of icky—the map isn't statically typed as `WithDefault`, so we have to use reflection. It's not the kind of reflection that's likely to inflict a significant performance penalty, but it's still far from ideal.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Try` instead of try/catch, and it would look a little cleaner.

```
val m = Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 4)

import scala.util.Try 

Try(m(10)).getOrElse(0)

res0: Int = 0

val m = Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 4).withDefaultValue(100)

Try(m(10)).getOrElse(0)

res1: Int = 100
```

Comment: it definitely looks nicer! though I'm hoping there's a way where I wouldn't have to call `apply` in a situation where it could throw an exception (if that's even possible)

Comment: Someone may correct me if I'm wrong, but it's not looking possible. It's the `Map`'s `default` method that throws the exception. If only it returned an `Option`, instead. Either way, you'd still have do some sort of check.