# How to get Map default value if it exist

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I would like to retrieve the default value of a Map, if it exists. Here is what I have tried:

```
def defaultValue[A, B](m: Map[A, B]): Option[B] = {
  m match {
    case m: Map.WithDefault[A, B] => Some(m.default(null))
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

This does not work because `null` is not a subtype of `A`. How to retrieve the default value of a `Map.WithDefault` which has a constant function?

**What I have tried**

Produce a random value of type `A`? Default values are encoded using constant functions, that's why it needs an argument, but in my case it should not happen that the argument is used. Furthermore, when I put something like `???` of type `Nothing`, it evaluates the argument before trying to return the constant value and thus throws an exception.

My problem is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702250/how-to-tell-if-a-map-has-a-default-value) but they do not provide a way to retrieve the default value directly.

Comment: Why rely on a map having a default value? Why not do `map.get(key).getOrElse(myDefault)`?

Comment: I am converting scala's collections to other kind of collections which can also have default values (but no functions). That's why I need to retrieve the default value. I don't need the value for a particular key.

Comment: There is no such thing as a map with a default value. Maps with default have a default function, which may or may not be constant. That's why the `default` method takes a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a lower bound, rewriting your method signature as:

```scala
def defaultValue[A >: Null <: AnyRef, B](m: Map[A, B]): Option[B]
```

---

Or alternatively you can cast `null` to `A` with `null.asInstanceOf[A]`:

```scala
case m: Map.WithDefault[A, B] => Some(m.default(null.asInstanceOf[A]))
```

Not that this version works also for `A <: AnyVal` (remember that e.g. `null.asInstanceOf[Int]` == 0).

---

Just one additional note: you can match against `case _: Map.WithDefault[_, _]` cause the outer reference in this type test cannot be checked at run time.

Comment: That's nice. How would I then handle the case when A may be a primitive type, such as an Integer, a Boolean, a Char, or anything else?

Comment: Just use the second version, the one with `null.asInstanceOf[A]`, without adding the lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by calling `#default` on any key:

```scala
val map = Map(1 -> "a").withDefaultValue("b")

map(1)         // yields "a"
map.default(1) // yields "b"
```

It's not that nice though and it will throw an exception if it has no default value, so you need to wrap it in a `Try` and then use pattern matching to extract it.

```scala
Try(map.default(1)).toOption match {
  case Some(value) => // do something with the value
  case _           => // do something else
}
```

Comment: That's a nice solution if I know the type. However, I'm working with generics and I don't have a value for the generic type `A`.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that. Given the fact you don't now if `A`  is at least a subtype of `AnyRef` to cast null as an instance and since `Nothing` has no instances I don't think you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use type class pattern to deal with your issue. You receive error becouse A can be AnyVal class like Int, Float etc. But you can simply overcome this limitation, consider the following:

```
trait DummyProvider[T] {
  def dummy: T
}

implicit def anyRefDummy[T >: Null] = new DummyProvider[T] {
  def dummy: T = null
}

implicit def numericDummy[T](implicit ev: Numeric[T]) = new DummyProvider[T] {
  def dummy: T = ev.zero
}
//probably needs to add instance for boolean
```

Now all you need to do in your code is something like this:

```
def defaultValue[A, B](m: Map[A, B])(implicit ev: DummyProvider[A]): Option[B] = {
  m match {
    case m: Map.WithDefault[A, B] => Some(m.default(ev.dummy))
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

Comment: Not bad but it's always hard to put the implicits in scope.

Answer (score 0):

### This is not possible

In general this is not possible, because the default "value" is actually a function. So there is no single default value in the general case.

The following sources are from Scala 2.12.*.

There exists the following in `scala.collection.immutable.Map`:

```
  /** The same map with a given default function.
   *  Note: `get`, `contains`, `iterator`, `keys`, etc are not affected by `withDefault`.
   *
   *  Invoking transformer methods (e.g. `map`) will not preserve the default value.
   *
   *  @param d     the function mapping keys to values, used for non-present keys
   *  @return      a wrapper of the map with a default value
   */
def withDefault[V1 >: V](d: K => V1): immutable.Map[K, V1] = new Map.WithDefault[K, V1](this, d)
```

And this is from `scala.collection.Map`:

```
  /** An abstract shell used by { mutable, immutable }.Map but not by collection.Map
   *  because of variance issues.
   */
  abstract class WithDefault[K, +V](underlying: Map[K, V], d: K => V) extends AbstractMap[K, V] with Map[K, V] with Serializable {
    override def size               = underlying.size
    def get(key: K)                 = underlying.get(key) // removed in 2.9: orElse Some(default(key))
    def iterator                    = underlying.iterator
    override def default(key: K): V = d(key)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, but I was more looking for a workaround instead of telling that it is not possible. See the accepted answer.